# What are nullary connectives in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Some sources include the symbols $\top$ and $\bot$ as elements of the alphabet for the formal language of propositional logic and call them *nullary connectives*, meaning they are logical connectives that take zero arguments. Though I've seen them being called *logical constants* as well.

I don't understand how I am supposed to think about them, how does a logical connective work that doesn't connect any statements?

Is $\top$ just always true and $\bot$ always false no matter what? If so, where's the distinction between those symbols (part of the formal language) and the (metalinguistic) concept of tautology/contradiction?

Why should one choose to include it in the language or not?

What especially trips me up is that wikipedia lists sets like $\{\rightarrow,\bot\}$ or $\{\nrightarrow,\top\}$ as functionally complete.

Sorry if the question is incoherent.

Comment: Well, they work exactly like the propostional symbols, except that for any interpration $\phi$, $\phi (\bot)=0$, and $\phi (\top)=1$.

Comment: Also there is no big deal about $\{\rightarrow,\bot\}$(for instance) being functionally complete, you can get $\neg a$ as $a\to\bot$ and $a\land b$ as $(a\to (b\to\bot )) \to \bot$ since $\land,\neg$ is functionally complete you may conclude.

Comment: Yes a constant truth-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, $\top$ and $\bot$ are special constants whose valuations are always set to true and false respectively. In other words, we always have $\models \top$ and $\models \neg \bot$.

It is, however, convenient to consider them as connectives ($0$-ary connectives, hence) when one is dealing with sets of connectives. One *never* writes the braces, but you can imagine eg $\top$ as an operator $\top ()$.

As to why $X :=\{\rightarrow,\bot\}$ and $Y := \{\nrightarrow,\top\}$ are functionally complete sets of connectives, it is enough to show that you can express the operators $\wedge$ and $\neg$. I leave you as an exercise to show that:

1. $\neg A \equiv A \rightarrow \bot$
2. $A \wedge B \equiv \big( A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow \bot) \big) \rightarrow \bot$ (with 1. that makes $X$ functionally complete)

(**edited**)

4. $\neg A \equiv \top \nrightarrow A$
5. $A \land B \equiv A \nrightarrow (\top \nrightarrow B)$ (with 3. that makes $Y$ functionally complete)

Comment: I did the exercise and tried to show functional completeness of those sets treating $\top$ and $\bot$ as propositional "variables" just like $A$ and $B$ except they're either just true or just false in the truth tables. However I got different results than you for 3. and 4. : $\neg A \equiv \top \nrightarrow A$ and $A \land B \equiv A \nrightarrow (\top \nrightarrow B)$ Is this correct?

Comment: @LinusDieLinse There isn't a unique solution indeed and yes you are correct, well done. Oh and by the way I made a mistake on point 3. and 4! I'll correct my answer using your suggestion. :-)

Comment: thank you! :) I understand $\top$ and $\bot$ as *constants*, but could you elaborate on how and why it is convenient to consider them as nullary *connectives*, and what a nullary connective is?

Comment: @LinusDieLinse It is convenient because you can speak of a "set of connectives instead of a "set with connectives and eventually some constants". That is really all there is to it.

Comment: @LinusDieLinse "What is a nullary connective?" Formally it is the unique function $\emptyset \mapsto \{a\}$ for some $a$.

Comment: @LinusDieLinse One reason to think of these as connectives is that a lot of the basic theorems about propositional logic are proved by induction on the structure of formulas, and so it's nice to avoid having a special case about constants in the definition of a formula.